# fopen Permission denied on a file with 777 permissions

Tags: php, fopen, file-permissions

Since the title of this post is pretty much self-explanatory, I'll just jump to the code :

```
echo sprintf('%o', fileperms('test.txt'))."<br/>";

fopen("test.txt", "w");
```

And with this I get :

```
100777
fopen(test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Any ideas ?

Edit : Problem solved : there were access control lists on the server that were not configured correctly.

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe SElinux blocks you? Try `ls -Z` on the file.

Answer (score 6):

I think its possible that you have write/read permissions on the file but not on the folder. Try this in the public root of your website and see if you can read or write the file.

For safe mode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), php doc's say the following:

> Note: When safe mode is enabled, PHP checks whether the directory in
>   which the script is operating has the same UID (owner) as the script
>   that is being executed.

Last you also need to be sure that php has access to the folder you are trying to write to.

Comment: I'll have a look at whether safe mode is enabled. As for the folder, the permissions are also set to 777.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue: folder was 777, but fopen does not worked.  fopen said permission deny. Make sure your script  have a 'good' permissions. maybe it will help you:

```
echo $dst, file_exists($dst) ? ' exists' : ' does not exist', "\n";
echo $dst, is_readable($dst) ? ' is readable' : ' is NOT readable', "\n";
echo $dst, is_writable($dst) ? ' is writable' : ' is NOT writable', "\n";
$fh = fopen($dst, 'w');
if ( !$fh ) {
    echo ' last error: ';
    var_dump(error_get_last());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is file ownership issue ... you can use this to find out the problem

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

$file = "a.jpg";

echo sprintf ( '%o', fileperms ( $file ) ), PHP_EOL;
echo posix_getpwuid ( fileowner ( $file ) ), PHP_EOL; // Get Owner
echo posix_getpwuid ( posix_getuid () ), PHP_EOL; // Get User

if (is_file ( $file )) {
    echo "is_file", PHP_EOL;
    ;
}

if (is_readable ( $file )) {
    echo "is_readable", PHP_EOL;
    ;
}

if (is_writable ( $file )) {
    echo "is_readable", PHP_EOL;
}

fopen ( $file, "w" );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, everything runs fine until the "is_writable" (the file apparently isn't). The owner and users aren't the same, but it shouldn't be a problem since every user has write permissions on this file... Right ?

Comment: Something this can be an issue ... except you have root user .. you many not be able to write to the file .. .try changing ownership with `chown` http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php and chnage file permission with `chmod` http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: I'll ask the server administrator to do that rightaway. But still, I don't get why PHP can't write to a file if all users are allowed to write to it :-s

Comment: I'm wondering that too! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414208/permission-denied-when-opening-file-with-file-get-contents-webbrowser-can-open/10414444

Comment: Eventually found the solution : there were ACLs on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue, and unfortunately the error message provided no clue to the actual reason. I had to give 777 to the file of the class included in the file that gave the error message. The error message only said the php file that calls that class, which already had 777.

So, check the file that is mentioned in the error message (let's say index.php), and then check which classes are instantiated within that file (class-file.php, class-writer.php, etc). Then check the permissions of those files (class-file.php, class-writer.php).

Once I gave permissions for the class file, it worked normally. Perhaps the webhost changed something in their config, since everything worked until a few days ago.