# Permission denied when opening file with file_get_contents; webbrowser can open it without problems

Tags: php, ftp, file-permissions

When using `file_get_contents()` to get the file contents of a text file on an FTP server at **ftp://ipaddress/somefile.txt**, I'm getting the following error:

> **Warning**: file_get_contents() [[function.file-get-contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)]: connect() failed: Permission denied in **filename.php** on line **1**

But when I access **ftp://ipaddress/somefile.txt** within my webbrowser, it's absolutely no problem.

Why can my browser open the text file, but can `file_get_contents()` not?

PS: I don't know if it has something to do with it, but the ini directive `allow_url_fopen` is **on**.

Comment: Probably because the ftp server owns the fil and PHP/webserver not.

Comment: it sounds like your http server has permissions on the file, but not the ftp server.  I'd look at either adding ftp to http's group or modify the folder to allow greater read access (ie. chmod 755)

Comment: How do you access the ftp? Don't you need credentials? If so, how did you login.

Comment: It's an external server, anywhere in the world. I just wrote `ftp://ipaddress/somefile.txt` in the address bar of the webbrowser, and the browser showed the file contents without any problems. I did not need to enter any credentials. So I don't understand why my browser can access the file for reading, but PHP cannot.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem.  Turns out it was a problem with SELinux on my server:

I ran this line from the terminal to reslove it:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use [readfile](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function like this and see if this gets the file contents:

```
readfile('ftp://anonymous:email@example.com@' . $ipAddress . '/somefile.txt');
```