# PHP - fopen(error.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Tags: php, apache2

I get an php (5.4) warning for this code:
fopen("error.log","w");

The warning
Warning: fopen(error.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in ...

The point is, that error.log exists and has 777 rights. What can I do?

I am using Apache2, php 5.4 on an ubuntu 10.04 system

Comment: Maybe it's in a place outside of PHP's configured "safe" paths.... please provide the full path of the document root and the file you're trying to write to.

Comment: You need to assign `o+x` permisson for the containing directory as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fopen Permission denied on a file with 777 permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376048/fopen-permission-denied-on-a-file-with-777-permissions)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. it was th o+x on the dir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)