# PHP: File not writable after changing permissions and ownership

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

In a PHP script , am getting below error when checked if a file is writable or not.

```
fopen(test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Please see blow details:

1. Apache service is running as user:apache, checked with:

   `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'`

2.Ownership of the file to be written and php script is changed to apache.

```
chown apache:apache test.txt 
chown apache:apache test.php
```

3.File permissions changed to:777

```
chmod 777 test.txt 
chmod 777 test.php
```

4.Tried setting:
Already tried solutions provided in:[fopen Permission denied on a file with 777 permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376048/fopen-permission-denied-on-a-file-with-777-permissions)

OS:Redhat Enterprise

Code:

```
<?php
echo getmyuid().':'.getmygid(); 
echo "<br/>";
echo exec('whoami');
echo "<br/>";
$dst = 'test.txt';
echo $dst, file_exists($dst) ? ' exists' : ' does not exist<br/>', "<br/>\n";
echo $dst, is_readable($dst) ? ' is readable' : ' is NOT readable', "<br/>\n";
echo $dst, is_writable($dst) ? ' is writable' : ' is NOT writable<br/>', "<br/>\n";
$fh = fopen($dst, 'w');
if ( !$fh ) {
    echo ' last error: ';
    var_dump(error_get_last());
}
```

Output:

```
33:33
apache
test.txt exists
test.txt is readable
test.txt is NOT writable

last error: array(4) { ["type"]=> int(2) ["message"]=> string(57) "fopen(test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied" ["file"]=> string(34) "/var/www/data/test2.php" ["line"]=> int(10) }
```

Comment: is your folder in which these files are present ownd by apache too?

Comment: Write permissions are needed on the files / folders you wish to modify, read access is also required all the way to `/`. Without more info, can't say much more.

Comment: Permissions exists:chmod 777 test.txt 
chmod 777 test.php

Comment: Or perhaps your PHP isn't trying to open the file you think it's trying to open.

Comment: On some configurations 777 permissions actually block you from accessing or writing to the files. Are you able to read test.txt at all? (i.e. with wget/browser)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At last reached the answer myself! I had to modify the SELinux configuration with chon command and apply permission as:`httpd_sys_rw_content_t`

```
chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/data/
```

along with:

```
chown -R apache:apache/var/www/data/
chmod -R a+rX /var/www/data/
```