# Permission denied with 777 folder, ownership checked

Tags: php, laravel, file

I was trying to save a file in Laravel. My code are basically like this:

```
use File;
$certificateFile = $request->file; 
\File::put(public_path('/uploads/certificate/student'), base64_decode($certificateFile));
```

This is how i created the /certificate/student folder:

```
if (!\File::isDirectory(public_path('/uploads'))) {
\File::makeDirectory(public_path('/uploads'), 0777, true, true);
}
if (!\File::isDirectory(public_path('/uploads/certificate'))) {
\File::makeDirectory(public_path('/uploads/certificate'), 0777, true, true);
}
if (!\File::isDirectory(public_path('/uploads/certificate/student'))) {
\File::makeDirectory(public_path('/uploads/certificate/student'), 0777, true, true);
}
```

I got the error (Permisson denied) at that \File::put() line.
The thing is, i checked and the folder and its root all have 777 permission, writeable, readable:

```
dd( 
    "Permission", substr(sprintf('%o',fileperms(public_path('/uploads/certificate/student'))), -4),
    "Readable ?", is_readable(public_path('/uploads/certificate/student')), 
    "Writable ?", is_writeable(public_path('/uploads/certificate/student')), 
    "File owner", fileowner(public_path('/uploads/certificate/student')), 
    "My script owner id", getmyuid());
```

and my result like this:

```
"Permission" 
"0777" 
"Readable ?" 
true 
"Writable ?" 
true 
"File owner"
0 
"My script owner id"
0
```

Did i do something wrong? Maybe the way i checked for owner ship? Cause i read [Baba's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376048/fopen-permission-denied-on-a-file-with-777-permissions) said that you should check that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Error: laravel.log could not be opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened)  .... 
The highest voted answer is your answer.

Comment: your public folder having this  '/uploads/certificate/'    directory or not ? is it already created or creating runtime ?

Comment: try giving 
chmod -R 755 public/uploads/certificate/

Comment: Akshay ak: I just edited my question. The folder you mentioned is created during runtime. Please check it out